# How can I alternate between using System Clock and Steady Clock in the same function?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I'm writing a console app containing an Ethernet protocol analyzing function in C++/Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition that I wish to call from two different scenarios or use cases (which never come mixed, it is either or).

1. When (in realtime) receiving a frame from an Ethernet socket
2. When reading a previously recorded frame from a pcap-file (Ethernet recording)

The analysis part of the function need, among other things, to keep track on the period of time passed between two frames and do things differently based on delays, etc.

Case 1 is easy; tag each frame with a *timepoint* from `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` and calculate duration by simple subtraction; `delay = t2 - t1;`

Case 2 is likewise easy; convert the *struct timeval* record part of the captured frame into a *timepoint* using `std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t()`.

Instead of maintaining two different (complex) functions (one based on *steady_clock* and another twin based on *system_clock*) I wish to have an "overloaded" function that handles both.

I've been looking for conversion between the two clocks but have experienced unexplainable effects, offsets, etc. (I could provide examples but I refrain from exposing my, I assume beginner's mistakes on Chrono)

A senior colleague sent me some Howard Hinnant threads and YT recordings which I am very grateful to have received and watched. I believe I have got what a *Duration* and a *Timepoint* is and is properly "scared" of using `.Count()` and other "exits"... ;-)

However, I have not come across any topic nor good example of how to mix/convert between different clocks. At present I have fallen back on having two different versions of the function; one using *steady_clock* & realtime data from sockets and **another** using *system_clock* & recorded data read from file.

Comment: Will you consider "static overload" (e.g. using a template)?

Comment: Why not make the clock a parameter to the function and then you just use the provided clock?  You can use a template (if you aren't already) so that you can make the clock type a template parameter.  This will also let your function work with different types of clocks if that is needed in the future, as long as they have the same interface.